# how to redo merge conflict resolution for cherrypick without losing the changes(after the commit)?

Tags: git

Here are the steps that have led to the issue:

1. Cherry picked a commit
2. Resolved the merge conflict
3. git add the files that were resolved
4. git commit
5. Then i realised, there are compilation errors. i have fixed them.

And now, how do i add these changes to the previous commit without having to resolve the merge conflict.
I am hesitant in trying to `git reset HEAD~` so that i don't lose the changes. it has been a long resolution.

will a `git reset HEAD~` work?

Comment: Just a side comment: if you were _cherry-picking_, you should have run `git cherry-pick --continue`, not `git commit` because you lost the metadata from the original revision. Not that `git commit` would not work.. it would, but it won't have the metadata from the original revision.

Comment: @eftshift0: cherry-pick squirrels away the message in advance so that `git commit` will actually work here. It's usually better just to go straight to `--continue` anyway when picking a range of commits, since you'll eventually have to continue. :-) I think the OP wasn't picking a range here, though.

Comment: thanks for the pro tip @eftshift0  Long way to master git

Comment: yes, i wasn't picking a range, but always good to learn @torek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git add <your-files>
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

or in a single command:

```
git commit -a --amend --no-edit
```

the flags:

- `-a` : commit all unstaged and staged changes (no need for `git add`)
- `--amend`: put the changes in the previous commit
- `--no-edit`: and keep the commit message as it was

---

> will a git reset HEAD~ work?

Yes, that is another but longer option, but gives the same result:

```
git reset HEAD~ # undo last commit
git add <your-files>
git commit -m "message"
```